# Magento : Clearing cache by URL with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, magento, caching

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

I'm using Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

I wants to clear the cache by URL with Regular Expression.

Every thing is working fine But my problem is

I have the URLs like

1. http://www.example.com/
2. http://www.example.com/index.php
3. http://www.example.com/index.php/adidas-black-t-shirt.html

Like this i have the URLs for 1st URL i'm using the following Regular Expression i can clear the cache `'^/(?:example\.com?)?$'`

And for 2nd URL `'^/(?:index\.php/?)?$'` Using this i can clear the cache but the problem is here it clearing the cache for 3rd URL also in this case.

How can i clear the cache for only 2nd URL

Anything wrong i did here ?

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> Anything wrong I did here? `^/(?:index\.php/?)?$`

Yes, although it was great that you used anchors.

1. After the `^` that asserts that we are at the beginning of the string, you immediately proceed to match a `/` that isn't there, then `index`. This cannot match there (we are missing the whole `http etc` part.)
2. The `?` at the end makes the whole match optional.

But your regex will work with this small tweak (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fT4rR8)):

```
^.*?index\.php/?$
```

**Explain Regex**

```
^                        # the beginning of the string
.*?                      # any character except \n (0 or more times
                         # (matching the least amount possible))
index                    # 'index'
\.                       # '.'
php                      # 'php'
/?                       # '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                         # possible))
$                        # before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         # string
```